# Textview gets width from dimen-sw600dp-land on runtime orientation change at In portrait

Tags: android, textview, orientation, scaling, dimension

In the `oncreate()` method I am changing the orientation to portrait.

If I start the activity when the device is in portrait mode everything works perfectly.

If I start the activity when the device is in landscape mode, each textview in the layout file gets its width from dimen-sw600dp-land.

Comment: `dimen-sw600dp-land`? did you mean `values-sw600dp-land/dimens.xml`?

Comment: What is the desired location to get textview width from in this case?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks for your reply.........   yes, values-sw600dp-land/dimens.xml

Comment: @NickUdell getting width from dimens.xml

Comment: `each textview in the layout file gets its width` ... the width should be **relative** (`wrap_content`, `match_parent` or `0dp` - in case you are using weights)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein .... Stien, I want to set constant width(from dimens.xml) because am using that textviews as a listview header.

Comment: Why not having them in % of the parent width? just stick them in a LinearLayout and use weights. Easy.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein... I have more than 10 number of columns, so I have to set my parent linear layout's width as a wrap_content. Then How can I set % of parent width.

Comment: You should set the LinearLayout (parent) as `match_parent`, then set the weights for each TextView to **1** and their widths to **0dp**. Easy.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein... I don't want to share the available screen space, because more than 10 columns looks congested..so i have linear layout(header) and listview in a horizontal scroll view.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein.. parent is horizontal scrollview only then why?

Comment: You might want to try this: https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution by updating the configuration,

```
Configuration conf = activity.getResources().getConfiguration();
     conf.orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                activity.getResources().updateConfiguration(
                        conf,
                        activity.getBaseContext().getResources()
                                .getDisplayMetrics());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the orientation of your activity to portrait do it in the manifest instead of your `onCreate` method like so:

```
<activity
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```

This way you will avoid that problem all together.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply........... I want to set orientation at runtime(not static).